# How do I a. unify three data frames into one, b. create a new column to identify variables from different data frames?

Tags: r

I have 3 different data frames, which I need to combine into one to run ANOVAs, create some graphs, and such. I also need to create a new variable that identifies from which data frame each data comes from. They're called NNA2, TRB, and AP. Each has different lengths, because of the number of participants in each one. I am running on R Studio.

I have already reduced these data frames from bigger ones by using subset(). Now I need to combine them. I tried creating a new data frame as a test, and it gave the following error, which is regarding the length:

> prueba <- data.frame(NNA2$Sexo, TRB$Sexo, AP$Sexo)
>   Error in data.frame(NNA2$Sexo, TRB$Sexo, AP$Sexo) : 
>     arguments imply differing number of rows: 510, 526, 301

I do not know how to solve the issue regarding the length of the data frames, and I do not know how to create a variable that identifies which data frame they come from. For that second part, I do not have a command.

Comment: We can use `library(rowr); cbind.fill(NNA2$Sexo, TRB$Sexo, AP$Sexo, fill = NA)`

Answer (score 0):

'Id' is the column that identifies the original data frame

```
NNA2$Id = 'NNA'
TRB$Id = 'TRB'
AP$Id = 'AP'
prueba = rbind(NNA2, TRB, AP)
```